# How to specify label to ui:outputText in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

How to specify label to ui:outputText in lightning component, as label attribute is not supported in ui:outputText?

I have tried `<h3 class="slds-text-heading--small">Label</h3>`. But its showing label above the field and not in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Use your code inside `<div>` tag
Try with   `<div class="slds-grid">`  or `<div style="display:inline-flex"/>`

**Eg:**

```
<div class="slds-grid"> 
<h3></h3> <UI:output text  value=" " />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a label tag like this and associate it with same aura:id as the for attribute on label :

```
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1" id="inline-text-label">My label</label>

  <ui:outputText  aura:id="text-input-id-1" class="field" value="{!item.JobType}"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use ui:outputtext, create tour own outputtext component who will have html tags you need :)

Something like

```
<aura:component>
   <aura:attribute name="label" type="String">
   <aura:attribute name="value" type="String">

<div>
   <label>{!v.label}</label>
   <span>{!v.value}</span>
</div>

</aura:component>
```

Of course you can replace/complete all the HTML parts of my example by what you need ( add SLDS classes for example )

Then you call it like

```
<c:MyOutputText label="Ze Label" value="The value" />
```

Comment: Can you [edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/159914/edit) your answer to provide more detail, maybe cite documentation, or provide a working example?

Comment: The component used in our project is too complicated to be shared. ( 10+ attributes, inheritance, etc .... ). I edited to post an obvious example, probably not needed to anyone who practised lightning for more than 10 mn.